# Fetch video from server through API using AVPlayer in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, alamofire, avplayer

I am trying to fetch video from server in AVPlayer.The data is in JSON format. I have given down data of JSON format too. The video is in .mp4 format.

But the video doesn't play. But before I tried to play the video from local storage of .mp4, it played successfully in AVPlayer. What is problem with my code? I am using Swift 3.

My code is :

//ViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import Alamofire


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var player:AVPlayer?
var playerController1 = AVPlayerViewController()
var player1:AVPlayer?
var dictDataImage:NSArray = NSArray()
var dictDataVideo: NSArray = NSArray()
var appDictionary:NSDictionary!



   @IBOutlet var videoPreviewLayer2: YTPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.videos()

    videoPreviewLayer2.delegate = self
}




 func videos(){

    let collectionviewone: String = "http://rillmark.academy/api/rillmark-academy/home-page-video"
    Alamofire.request(collectionviewone, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response.result)
            if let JSON = response.result.value{

                self.appDictionary = (JSON as AnyObject) as! NSDictionary

                print("self.app =",self.appDictionary)


                let url1: URL = URL(string: (self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "home_video")) as! String)!


                let url4 = url1.absoluteString

                print("url11=", url1)
                print("url22=", url4)

                let url3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url4)
                let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url3 as URL)
                print("item=", item)
                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
                self.playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                self.playerController.player = self.player
                self.playerController.view.frame = self.videoPreviewLayer.frame
                self.videoPreviewLayer.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
                self.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
                self.playerController.player?.play()

            }
    }

}
}
```

//JSON

```
{
"status": "Success",
"home_video": "http://video/homepage/e27U0B_1502445369-homepage-2.mp4",
}
```